# Class illuminate validation rules password not found

Tags: laravel, validation

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
        
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Paginator::useBootstrap();
        Password::defaults(function(){
           return Password::min(8)->mixedCase()->numbers()->symbols()->uncompromised();
          });

    }
}
```

I am trying to add a default password rules to my laravel app but i am getting the error  class illuminate \Validation\Rules\password not found.

Comment: instead of image add code

Comment: i have done that

Answer (score 0):

Composer update did the magic for me.